# Invalid 'retry' Ruby (/rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I am trying to compare a current attribute with each attribute that is already in the database. If a certain condition is met, I want to break the loop, run a piece of code, and restart the loop.

```
User.all.each do |user|
  if user.name == obj_user.name
   count += 1
   retry
  end
end
```

Comment: There's probably a more efficient way to do this than force-restarting the loop each time. What about creating a mapping table using `group_by`? This will only work on trivial amounts of data. Running this on a site with 100K users will just crash your process because it will take way too much memory to load all those models.

Comment: How about selecting the count of users that have the same name from the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I don't see any cases to do it the way you are trying but still:

```
User.each do |user|
  begin
    raise if user.name == obj_user.name
  rescue
    count += 1
    retry
  end
end
```